# Parallelogram and CSGRegion

Tags: graphics, regions

I use Mathematica 13.1.0.0 and Windows 10.

I defined a Parallelogram and a Disk.

If I draw the **first** Graphics using them I can get the **second** Graphics to look exactly like it, as expected, after applying RegionUnion.

But as showed in the **third** Graphics I cannot make it look like **first** when I use CSGRegion. Why?

For the **third** Graphics to look like the **first**, as in the **fourth** Graphics, I have to divide by 2 all the dimensions defined for Parallelogram or, as in the **fifth** Graphics, I have to resort to Rectangle and Triangle.

Have any clues? Maybe it is a bug. Tks.

```
    pll = Parallelogram[{5, 7}, {{3, 0}, {2, 2}}];
    dsk = Disk[{6, 8}, 1];
    Column@{
      Graphics[{pll, dsk}, Axes -> True],
      Graphics[DiscretizeRegion@RegionUnion[pll, dsk], Axes -> True],
      Graphics[CSGRegion["Union", {pll, dsk}], Axes -> True],
      Graphics[
       CSGRegion[
        "Union", {Parallelogram[{5, 7}/2, {{3, 0}, {2, 2}}/2], dsk}], 
       Axes -> True],
      Graphics[
       CSGRegion[
        "Union", {Triangle[{{5, 7}, {7, 7}, {7, 9}}], 
         Rectangle[{7, 7}, {8, 9}], Triangle[{{8, 7}, {8, 9}, {10, 9}}], 
         dsk}], Axes -> True]}
```

[image]

Comment: A bug.  `CSGRegion["Union", {pll, pll}, Axes -> True]`.

Comment: Graphics[CSGRegion["Union", {pll, dsk}], Axes -> True] gives obviously a wrong answer. The parallelogram is in the wrong place. Please report this to support@wolfram.com.

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:bugs] tag on new questions you ask. See the tag description for more information. Please find appropriate tags and re-tag this question.

Comment: - Daniel. Reported already. Parallelogram is not only in the wrong place but it has the wrong size.

Comment: - cvgmt - Very clever!

Comment: Even if Parallelogram is changed to Parallelepiped in pll = Parallelogram[{5, 7}, {{3, 0}, {2, 2}}]  the third Graphics will still  show the same defect.